# logback-access configuration

Tags: tomcat6, logback, maven-tomcat-plugin

I am trying to configure logback-access for spring based tomcat application. Have added following lines in my pom.xml file:

```
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <version>${logback.version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${logback.version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
                    <version>${logback.version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
```

I have also added this in tomcat plugin configuration of the pom file.

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.tomcat.plugin}</version>           
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <logback.ContextSelector>JNDI</logback.ContextSelector>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>                
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <version>${logback.version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${logback.version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
                    <version>${logback.version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>   
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

I have put resource files at following location:
src/main/resources/logback.xml
src/main/resources/logback-access.xml

But while the logback.xml works, tomcat is not able to pick up the logback-access.xml file. How do i attach the access xml file with my tomcat6 plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying the same but I discovered that tomcat6/7-maven-plugin's do not have the capability to run these configuration because this has to be configured at the container level
refer http://logback.qos.ch/access.html#tomcat

You can use "cargo-maven2-plugin" to run the application in existing container and configure that container for the logback-access

### Configure Cargo Something like this

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cargo.maven.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                    <type>installed</type>
                    <home>${tomcat.home}</home>
                    <timeout>1800000</timeout> 
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <type>existing</type>
                    <home>${tomcat.home}</home>
                </configuration>
                <deployables>
                    <deployable>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>YOUR_WEB_ARTIFICT</artifactId>
                        <type>war</type>
                    </deployable>
                </deployables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

---

I used cargo plugin version 1.3.3

then execute cargo:deployer-deploy

and cargo:run  or cargo:start